# MySQL fetch record as in order passed for IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Want result in same order as passed to IN condition:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_x` WHERE `id` IN (30, 12, 1001, 24);
```

**Getting:**

```
id    | field_a | field_b
--------------------------
12    | ...     | ...
24    | ...     | ...
30    | ...     | ...
1001  | ...     | ...
```

**Expecting:**

```
id    | field_a | field_b
--------------------------
30    | ...     | ...
12    | ...     | ...
1001  | ...     | ...
24    | ...     | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_x` 
WHERE `id` IN (30, 12, 1001, 24) 
order by field(id, 30, 12, 1001, 24)
```

Comment: How can I do this same in PostgreSQL. I did same here [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9742c/8](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9742c/8) but throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) for FIELD function

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa177/5/0)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table_x` 
  WHERE `id` IN (30, 12, 1001, 24) 
  ORDER BY FIELD(id, 30, 12, 1001, 24);
```

You will get output as

```
|   ID | FIELD_A | FIELD_B |
|------|---------|---------|
|   30 |     ... |     ... |
|   12 |     ... |     ... |
| 1001 |     ... |     ... |
|   24 |     ... |     ... |
```

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA i have forgot to add field function. TQs for review it. And view my posted answer included SQLFiddle

Comment: How can I do this same in PostgreSQL. I did same here [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9742c/8](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9742c/8) but throwing error.

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA in postgreSQL function FIELD() not available, see updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6cd1c/2 giving some error

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA you can do it by using creating a function in PostgreSQL. Nice example explained here http://paramitech.com/postgres-order-by-field/

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA once observe this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6cd1c/11/0 achieved in PostgreSQL , explained here http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/ORDER-BY-FIELD-feature-td1901324.html :)